# Paginaion in firestore: Jump to a specific page without knowing the first document in that page

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection with thousands of documents and I need to implement a pagination system where:

1. Only 20 documents will be rendered at a time
2. Documents will be sorted by let's say, a **created_at** timestamp field.
3. One more very important requirement is that the user should be able to jump to a specific page directly without having to go through all the previous pages first. For example, open the 9th page directly.

Here's my attempt:

```
import { getDocs, query, collection, orderBy, getFirestore, startAt, limit } from 'firebase/firestore';

const pageSize = 20;

async function fetchPage(page: number){
    const db = getFirestore();
    const offset = page * pageSize;
    const q = query(
        collection(db, 'order'),
        orderBy('created_at'),
        limit(pageSize),
        startAt(offset));
    return await getDocs(q);
}

fetchPage(9).then(snapshot => {
    console.log('Documents loaded: ', snapshot.docs);
});
```

The above code always loads the first 20 documents in the collection regardless of the page number and regardless of whatever integer value I provide to the startAt method, it just has no impact on the results.

Answer (score 1):

The code you write will not do what you intend. Instead it will return the first `pageSize` documents with `created_at > offset`. There is no offset in Firestore client.

But, depending on your needs, you could for instance hack it this way:

1. Add the document number modulo 20 in a field of each document, say `page`
2. Keep the total number of documents in a separate central document. You will need to increment it every time a document in 1 is created.

Then it depends what you mean by page nth:

- the nth set of 20 docs created from the start => then easy, just add `where('page','==',n)` to your query.
- the nth set of 20 latest documents (eg page 1 = 20 last documents) then you will have to to some math but by retrieveing documents for at most 2 consecutive `page` (so 40 docs) you are always sure to get the 20 you want.

Note that

1. this solution requires that you first read the current total document number and then create the new document and increment the total number - all this in a transaction to avoid concurrent issues. [This will limit the rate at which you can create documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#designing_for_scale).
2. Consequently it will cost you 1 more read and 2 more write each time
3. This solutions does not work if you can delete documents

Comment: I'm so disappointed in firestore tbh. Every time I need to do some very basic task but for firestore it feels like I'm asking for too much! I'm greedy just because I wanted proper pagination for my data

Comment: The answer I suggested, will give you proper pagination. Just needs some additional efforts